# Terminated due memory pressure

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory, instruments

I got the problem when my app is running in background on my iPhone for more than 2 hours, then in Xcode often comes the error "Terminated due memory pressure". What can I do that my app runs in background without problems? Here's a screenshot of Instruments:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Use the profile to see what's happening and fix / stop it. No specific advice without specific details about the app...

Comment: @Wain What do you mean with profile?

Comment: "What can I do that my app runs in background without problems?": Use less memory.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Is 3.11 MB a lot?

Comment: No, that's not a lot. But when tracing memory allocations with Instruments, according my observations, this will also cause the device to allocate memory (not your app, but the system). How does it work without tracing memory allocations, say just using the profiler?

Comment: Another reason is, that "terminating due to memory pressure" is *normal* for a background process. The system needs RAM, and it decided to kill your app - for what ever reason. Well, there might be other apps coming to foreground and recklessly asking for huge chunks of memory. These "ego-centric" apps, may also be the reason that your app gets killed.  ;)

Comment: Yep, this isn't necessarily a reflection on your app, other than it probably claims a lot of storage when in background.  It's other foreground apps and their need for storage that is causing yours to be killed.  You can maybe help a bit by figuring out how to reduce your backgrounded storage requirements even more.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem in a tracking app. Is there a way to get notified when iOS kills the process ? all i need is send a notification to let user know that app has stopped doing its work ( so that it may resume the task restarting app ).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put, it's very likely not really your fault. The iOS low memory killer (a rather aggressive kernel thread by the name of Jetsam) uses "priority bands" to maintain candidate processes to kill on low memory, and virtually everyone is a candidate - with background processes being likelier than foreground ones. [image: Priority bands in Jetsam, from newosxobook.com/articles/MemoryPressure.html].  (Image taken from Priority bands in Jetsam, from http://newosxbook.com/articles/MemoryPressure.html)

What you can do is try to gain some more breathing room by responding to low memory events (i.e. implement didReceiveLowMemoryWarning) and unload any Images/UIImageViews, etc you aren't strictly requiring - even if you do a little, it helps you survive. Also, you didn't point out which UIBackgroundMode you are using - that might help (it defines app profile in kernel, thereby taming Jetsam a little).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your link is broken.

Comment: How much is "a little"? Would it be enough to release just one memory-page (4K) to mollify Jetsam for a while?